# How do you switch between Linux manual pages?

Tags: linux, man

I'm new with Linux and have noticed that there are numbers beside certain commands I look up.

For example I want to look up `accept()` in the aspect of network programming, but `man accept` shows this instead:

```
accept(8)                   Easy Software Products                   accept(8)

NAME
       accept/reject - accept/reject jobs sent to a destination
```

So how do you switch between manual pages to other numbers like `accept(1)` ~ `accept(7)`?

Comment: Nowadays you can read manpages on the web too: http://linux.die.net/man/

Comment: @ott Also, Google Chrome has a man pages plugin, so one can type "man popen" and it will automatically load the relevant man page from an online source (eg linux.die.net).

Comment: @ott--: Yes, but any man pages on the web aren't necessarily in sync with the software on your system.

Comment: The `man` command has its own man page; typing `man man` would have answered this and many other questions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To find out which sections are available, use `whatis manpage`. Example:

```
$ whatis unlink
unlink (2)           - delete a name and possibly the file it refers to
unlink (1)           - call the unlink function to remove the specified file
```

To view the manual page in question, use `man section manpage`, e.g.:

```
man 2 unlink
```

Using the `-a` option, you'll be able to show all sections of a manpage:

```
man -a unlink
```

I haven't found a way to "switch" between manpages even though the pager `less` supports switching (`:p` and `:n`), the only supported actions using the `-a` option are "next", "skip" and "cancel".

When in doubt, you can also read the manual page of `man`:

```
man man
```

Answer (score 17):

The 8 referenced there isn't actually page 8, it is section 8.  The sections are split like this:

```
Section     Description
1   General commands
2   System calls
3   C library functions
4   Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5   File formats and conventions
6   Games and screensavers
7   Miscellanea
8   System administration commands and daemons
```

So the *accept* you are reading about is the system admin command.

If a command is in more than one section, you will be prompted for the one you want, or you can use:

```
man 8 accept
```

Where "8" is the section.  This will target the specific man page section you are after.

Comment: I've never been prompted when a name is in more than one section--man has just shown me the first one. You can, though, use the -a option to be taken to all the pages of that name in sequence, or the -k option to see a list of all the pages containing that name in their short descriptions.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, this helps a lot! Is there a keyboard shortcut to simply switch between sections?

Comment: @Sheldon man is not GNU info - its just a program which prints out manual pages, and does not use a built in explorer.

Answer (score 5):

`man 2 accept` will display section 2, for example.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, For less-forgiving *NIX environments (Mac/Darwin, Solaris, AIX, ... ) may not accept

```
man 2 accept
```

you would need to use `-S 2` instead:

```
man -S 2 accept
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to run

`man -a name`

This will show in sequence all the manual pages for "name" in all volumes where they appear.